# Installing Torchaudio for PyTorch 1.10.0 with CUDA 11.0

Tags: pytorch, ubuntu-18.04, mamba, torchaudio

On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine I have a virtual environment that contains `pytorch=1.10.0=cuda110py38hf84197b_0`. My CUDA version is 11.0, which I've checked by running `nvidia-smi`. I would like to install torchaudio.

I've attempted this using `mamba install torchaudio=0.10.0 -c pytorch`. However, this tries to upgrade the cuda build of my pytorch from 11.0 to 11.2. Similarly, if I try installing torchaudio=0.9.1, mamba wants to downgrade my pytorch version from 1.10.0 to 1.9.1.

This is an old machine with several-year-old code that relies on these old packages. Ideally, I would be able to install torchaudio with modifying as few packages/cuda drivers as possible. Is there a way to install torchaudio for pytorch 1.10.0 cuda build 11.0? I've checked the [official pytorch releases page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) and it seems like this option isn't even listed (so maybe I've already answered my own question, but I'm trying here as well).

For reference, here is a basic environment containing my pytorch-necessary packages. Thank you.

```
name: torchbase
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_llvm
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7f98852_4
  - ca-certificates=2023.11.17=hbcca054_0
  - cffi=1.15.0=py38h3931269_0
  - cudatoolkit=11.0.3=h15472ef_9
  - cudnn=8.2.1.32=h86fa8c9_0
  - future=0.18.2=py38h578d9bd_4
  - icu=68.2=h9c3ff4c_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.36.1=hea4e1c9_2
  - libblas=3.9.0=12_linux64_mkl
  - libcblas=3.9.0=12_linux64_mkl
  - libffi=3.4.2=h7f98852_5
  - libgcc-ng=11.2.0=h1d223b6_11
  - libiconv=1.16=h516909a_0
  - liblapack=3.9.0=12_linux64_mkl
  - libnsl=2.0.0=h7f98852_0
  - libprotobuf=3.18.1=h780b84a_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0=he4da1e4_11
  - libuuid=2.32.1=h7f98852_1000
  - libxml2=2.9.12=h72842e0_0
  - libzlib=1.2.11=h36c2ea0_1013
  - llvm-openmp=12.0.1=h4bd325d_1
  - magma=2.5.4=h4a2bb80_2
  - mkl=2021.4.0=h8d4b97c_729
  - nccl=2.11.4.1=h96e36e3_0
  - ncurses=6.2=h58526e2_4
  - ninja=1.10.2=h4bd325d_1
  - numpy=1.22.3=py38h99721a1_2
  - openssl=1.1.1o=h166bdaf_0
  - pip=23.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python=3.8.12=hb7a2778_2_cpython
  - python_abi=3.8=2_cp38
  - pytorch=1.10.0=cuda110py38hf84197b_0
  - pytorch-gpu=1.10.0=cuda110py38h5b0ac8e_0
  - readline=8.1=h46c0cb4_0
  - setuptools=60.1.1=py38h578d9bd_0
  - sleef=3.5.1=h9b69904_2
  - tbb=2021.5.0=h4bd325d_0
  - tk=8.6.11=h27826a3_1
  - typing_extensions=4.0.1=pyha770c72_0
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h516909a_1
  - zlib=1.2.11=h36c2ea0_1013
  - zstd=1.5.1=ha95c52a_0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, unfortunately, there is no such an option.

I think upgrading pytorch-CUDA from 11.0 to 11.2 is less critical then downgrading the `pytorch` version. In the first case it is minor version change `11.0 -> 11.2`, in a last - it's (almost) major: `1.10.0 -> 1.9.1`